# PHP/Wordpress Newbie

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress I am trying to get all posts within multiple categories. Heres my code:

```
 <?php 
             // Get categories
             $menu = 'left-column-menu';
             $cat_args = array(
                'order'                  => 'ASC',
                'orderby'                => 'menu_order',
                'post_type'              => 'nav_menu_item',
                'post_status'            => 'publish',
                'output'                 => ARRAY_A,
                'output_key'             => 'menu_order',
                'nopaging'               => true,
                'update_post_term_cache' => false );

             $cat_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu, $cat_args ); 

              // Get categories posts
             $args = array(
                'posts_per_page'   => '',
                'offset'           => 0,
                'category'         => $cat_items->ID,
                'orderby'          => 'post_date',
                'order'            => 'DESC',
                'include'          => '',
                'exclude'          => '',
                'meta_key'         => '',
                'meta_value'       => '',
                'post_type'        => 'post',
                'post_mime_type'   => '',
                'post_parent'      => '',
                'post_status'      => 'publish',
                'suppress_filters' => true ); 

               $posts = get_posts($args); 

                    print_r($posts);

             ?>
```

The first part is getting the categories from a menu, this is working fine. But its only getting the first 5 posts. I'm just wondering why this is?

Comment: because by default it takes 5, try giving 'posts_per_page'=>-1

Comment: Thank you Neo, its always the simple thing's that get me :( I thought it was somehow in a for loop as the number of categories is 5.

Comment: When can I mark your answer as correct?

Comment: i just added a comment....didn't give an answer as there wasn't any need of it, it was just a small thing you missed...still you can upvote my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
// Get categories posts
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => '',
```

To:

```
// Get categories posts
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
```